# How to calclate Drude dielectric function vs probe energy from time resolve spectroscopy?

Tags: optics, laser, electronic-band-theory, non-linear-optics, laser-interaction

How can I calculate drude dielectric function vs probe energy (in eV) form differential transmittance vs delay time plots.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you'll need terahertz or microwave probe for that.

The IR probe only tells you the population of mobile carriers, but not conductivity.

The best way to measure dielectric response is **Time-Resolved Terahertz Spectroscopy**. It give you time and frequency resolved **complex** conductivity/refractive index/dielectric function.
To obtain single coherent terahertz pulse you need to use your mode-lock laser (preferably sub-100fs):

1 - Optical rectification  (at least 1mJ pulse)

2 - Air plasma generation (at least 1mJ pulse)

3 - Photo-conductive antenna (at least 20nJ pulse, depending on the size of antenna)